# read elements from iFrame in django

Tags: python, django, iframe, django-templates

I use the following code to access a check-box element in the IFrame. I expect to get one of the messages due to the check-box status, but it always responds: "The check-box is not checked." How can I fix the problem?

```
def main_page():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_to_response('main.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('checkbox1', False):
            return HttpResponse("The check-box is checked.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("The check-box is not checked.")
def iFrame():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_to_response('MyIFrame.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return
```

Where this is the template for main.html:

```
    <form>
        <iframe src="MyIFrame.html"></iframe>
        <input name="button" type="submit" id="button" value="ok">
    </form>
```

And this is the template for MyIFrame.html:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1">
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? An iframe is not part of the same document, the form data won't include any inputs from the iframe. Why aren't you using normal template inheritance?

Comment: the `iframe` is a whole separate document, it is not part of the form in the parent page

Comment: Thanks. I know that iFrame is independent from the parent page, but is there any way to access its elements from the parent?